# Repeat unittest every 3 minutes

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing

I am working on a web monitor script that will just run through some pages and check that everything is displayed via selenium. I have everything setup and working and the only thing I need to do is somehow setup the test to repeat it self every 3 minutes.

I tried to somehow flip it into the tearDownClass that it would just wait a while and then reboot the test but that didnt work. Also tried to write it into the main function like this - when I look at it now that does not make too much sense to me but wanted to mention it.

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     while True:
        unittest.main()
        time.sleep(5)
        TEST(unittest.TestCase)
```

I also tried to "convert" the whole test case in to a function that would just loop in while True statement but that didnt work either.
I googled and found a pytest-repeat but that sadly doesnt work with Unittest that I use currently.

Anyone have any idea how to do that please? Will be happy to hear any thoughts so thanks in advance! I hope everything is clear if not please let me know

Comment: are you familiar with cron?

Comment: Not really, but I will google it and see what I can find. Thanks!